# How to wire a click event from one div's child to another div's child of equal count in the dom tree?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to achieve a weird edge case with javascript and I'm stuck. I want to fire a click from one parent's child to another parent's child, but the children should match in order of the dom tree, so when user clicks on `foo2` I need to trigger a click on `bar2`. `foo3` would trigger `bar3` and so on.

I have an added challenge where I cannot edit the html of `target` as that data is being loaded externally from an API

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var target = document.querySelector('.target');

parent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
 console.log(e.target);
  
  // clicking a .parent child would trigger a click on
  // matching child list-item in .target 
  // i.e. clicking foo2 would trigger a click on bar2
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#">foo1</a>
  <a href="#">foo2</a>
  <a href="#">foo3</a>
  <a href="#">foo4</a>
</div>

<ul class="target">
  <li>bar1</li>
  <li>bar2</li>
  <li>bar3</li>
  <li>bar4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var parentChildren = Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children)` to get the children of the div `parent`

and use `var targetChildren = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.children)` to get children of the ul `target`

Then onclick of any element in `parentChildren`, trigger the click of same index in `targetChildren`

like this:

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var target = document.querySelector('.target');

var parentChildren = Array.prototype.slice.call(parent.children);
var targetChildren = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.children);

parent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  targetChildren[parentChildren.indexOf(e.target)].click()
});

// Added this listener for illustration.
target.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#">foo1</a>
  <a href="#">foo2</a>
  <a href="#">foo3</a>
  <a href="#">foo4</a>
</div>

<ul class="target">
  <li>bar1</li>
  <li>bar2</li>
  <li>bar3</li>
  <li>bar4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can create a trigger in your a tags by using the `href="Javascript: foo()"` (where foo could be replaced by any function). Then you can set ids to each item in your target list by using `document.getElementsByClasses("target")[i].innerHTML` and using a for loop to give each one an id in relation to their name. In your function, use `document.getElementById("foo")` to access the specific target list value. You can apply things by using `document.getElementById("foo").style.(whatever you want)`

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble upwards, so you won't be able to catch the same event with the user's click, on a sibling our cousin element.

But inside of your event listener, when the user clicks, you can grab the element that you want to also be clicked, and trigger the click even on it:

```
 element.click()
```